# How to fix "Unable to remove directory 'Shared'. Access to the path 'obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Razor\Pages\Shared' is denied"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm developing a web app using ASP.NET Core, and the Visual Studio compiler is throwing

> Error MSB3231: "Unable to remove directory "Shared". Access to the
>   path '[Path to Visual Studio
>   Project]\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Razor\Pages\Shared' is denied."

The error is being thrown in an ASP.NET file, so it's not something I've done incorrectly.

I've tried manually deleting the directory and using an elevated command prompt, and neither worked. This issue had occured for me in the past, and I was able to solve it by booting into safe mode and deleting it there. The only issue with that is it's quite a pain to have to reboot my laptop twice (into safe mode and back into normal mode) when this comes up. Note that this error has come up twice already.

Comment: You might want to always run Visual Studio itself with elevated permissions (enable *Run as Admin* in the shortcut). This solves lots of permission issues, such as not being able to debug when running on IIS. What you experience might be another one of such issues.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work

Comment: Where did you create this project? Try to create a new project which is not in `C Disk`, make sure you have the full permission for this project folder.

Comment: it didn't work for me :-(

Answer (score 2):

1. Under Visual Studio "**solution explorer**" tab
2. Right click your project then "**Open Folder in file explorer**"

[image]

3. Windows will open the folder , you shall see a folder name "**obj**" , double click and navigate into
4. Delete everything under "**obj**" , included "**Debug**" folder
5. Go back visual studio and hit "**F5**" debug , which will compile your project again and fix the error .

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to the permissions of the folder, and give it to your user, then try again.

Comment: I don't have permission to modify the directory's permission settings..

Comment: Hum, that's a problem, can you at least change the projects directory to another one and try it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the fix but as a workaround, please try to see if all the projects in your solution are targeting to the same framework. I was getting the same error until I changed one of my angular project to point to .net core 3.1.

Comment: This one did it for me...One was targeting 3.0 the other one was targeting 3.1 Thank you